# Putting a Street View Button on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I put a Street View button on a fairly typical Google Map so that it is inline with the standard Map/Satellite/Hybrid buttons in the top right corner?  I've seen one example of this that I can't find any longer.  So, I know it's possible.

Comment: Isn't that the way it used to appear on the Google site?  Maybe if you use the old API instead of the current one, you'll get that behavour?

Comment: Using the old API isn't an option.

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed, one can specify control positions in the map's options--look for *control positioning* in the [online docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls).

### How to specify Google maps controls positions

For positioning the street view control in the top right corner add

```
  streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  }
```

to your map's options.

Check this demo (that uses the Google maps API version 3):

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151);
var myOptions = {
  center: myLatlng,
  zoom: 5,
  streetViewControl: true,
  streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Here's an [another example for control positioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning) in the official documentation.

#### Control placement identifiers

These are all possible positions for Google maps controls (from `TOP_LEFT` to `BOTTOM_RIGHT`):

```
  +----------------+ 
  + TL    TC    TR + 
  + LT          RT + 
  +                + 
  + LC          RC + 
  +                + 
  + LB          RB + 
  + BL    BC    BR + 
  +----------------+
```

For a full list of positions and how they work see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ControlPosition

### Changing a control position programmatically

You can also change the position dynamically after creating the map using the `SetOptions` method of the [`google.maps.Map` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map). In this example I create a map as above with `streetViewControl` in position `TOP_RIGHT` and then change it to `LEFT_BOTTOM`:

```js
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151);
var myOptions = {
  center: myLatlng,
  zoom: 5,
  streetViewControl: true,
  streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

// now change position to LEFT_BOTTOM changing streetViewControlOptions
// with setOptions
map.setOptions({
  streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
});
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```